# How to get data from different doc to a different collection in flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I want to fetch data from my cart collection where i am storing user has added which item in his cart by using the doc id of the product now i want to show all item to user cart which he has added but i don't know how to do because I am only storing the product id so does any one know the solution for it ??

Cart collection Firestone

[image]

Products collection firestore

[image]

i haven't tried anything as i am new to flutter Firebase and don't have much knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to query with user id by where query.
Check out the code.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

// Assuming you have a function to get the user's cart items
Future<List<String>> getUserCartItems(String userId) async {
  List<String> cartItems = [];
  
  QuerySnapshot cartSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('cart')
    .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
    .get();
    
  cartSnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    // Assuming your cart document has a field called 'productId'
    cartItems.add(doc['productId']);
  });

  return cartItems;
}
```

Comment: i have one more doubt like how to show the information in listview builder ? because i am using widget.